# Angular 9 - How to correctly compare a copied Object for changes?

Tags: angular, object, copy

I have an API call that returns some data:

```
this.myAPI.getProfile().subscribe(result => {
        this.currentProfile = result;
});
```

Now in my project, the user can edit profile informations, and to enter Edit mode, he clicks on a button.

On entering Edit mode, I make a copy of the current Profile object, so in case the user reverts the changes (by using the "Cancel" button), I will restore the original data.

```
this.currentProfileCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.currentProfile));
```

Everything works great, but I have an issue, I want to keep the "Save" button disabled if no informations have been changed, so the check there would be:

```
this.currentProfile == this.currentProfileCopy
```

The problem is, this check never returns true.
I guess it has to do with the `JSON.stringify`.

I also tried:

```
 JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.currentProfile)) == this.currentProfileCopy
```

This also returns always false..

What is the correct way to implement this?

**IMPORTANT:** I cannot use LoDash, only Angular methods, as I'm using a framework that builds Angular code, cannot import external libraries.
I also cannot use stuff like valueChanges and so on, I need to do this by comparing the original object and a copy of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no 1 solution for comparing objects. It all depends on your object and what (type of) data it holds.

Based on your limited information I can only suggest comparing it based on the JSON string, so something like this:
`JSON.stringify(this.currentProfile) === JSON.stringify(this.currentProfileCopy)`

Comment: the object holds standard strings and integers (first name, last name, userID).

Anyway this works...I tried every combination but not this one, as I assumed that the copied object was already "stringified" as I used that method to copy it in the first place...good thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `JSON.stringify` method for both sides of that comparison.

```
JSON.stringify(this.currentProfile) === JSON.stringify(this.currentProfileCopy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lodash` library. To compare two objects you can use the `isEqual` function.

https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual