# Copy Data Object to compare to original - Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, reference

How do I copy a data object so that I can compare a changed copy to original data?

I have tried making a copy of my data using the spread operator, but somehow, my original data is being changed.

### Context

I have a screen in my app that allows the user to edit an array of key/value pairs.

Here is an example interface that this particular screen uses

```
interface Account {
     tokens: {key: string, value: string}[],
     ...
```

In my view, I loop over each token, and display input fields so that the user can edit the data of the tokens. I also want to apply a class to the parent element if the particular token is dirty.

```
<div class="token" *ngFor="let token of account.tokens" [ngClass="{'is-dirty': isTokenDirty(token)}">
     Key: <input [(ngModel)]="token.key"/>
     Value: <input [(ngModel)]="token.value"/>
</div>
```

Finally, here is what my component looks like:

```
@component {
     account: Account;
     existingTokens: {key: string, value: string}[];

     ngOnInit() {
           extistingTokens = [...this.account.tokens];
     }

     
  isTokenDirty(token: { key: string; value: string }) {
    const existingToken = this.existingTokens.find(t => t.key == token.key);
    if(existingToken) {
       // this always returns false
      return (token.value != existingToken.value);
    }
    // new token
    return true;
  }
```

My `isTokenDirty` function will always return false. How is it that the data in my `existingTokens` property changes when my view changes? Shouldn't `existingTokens` be completely independent from my `account.tokens` property, since i'm using a spread operator to copy the data?

Comment: You should probably try to provide a minimal reproducible example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally, someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like Stackblitz ([link here!](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy)) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. There should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: well, i'm seeking conceptual understanding rather than an immediate solution.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer in this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570203/angular-9-how-to-correctly-compare-a-copied-object-for-changes) works for me.

`this.existingTokens = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.account.tokens));`

It seems I did not understand that the spread operator only copies one level deep.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals